# use laravel advanced where clauses to run a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Suppose I have a `Course` Model like this :

```
class Course extends Model
    {
        public function users ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'course_user', 'course_id', 'user_id');

        }

        public function lessons ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson', 'course_id', 'course_id');
        }
    }
```

`Course` fields are :

```
course_id
title
```

Each Course can have multiple lessons.

`Lesson` Model is like :

```
class Lesson extends Model
{
public function course ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Course', 'course_id', 'course_id');
        }
public function users ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'lesson_user', 'lesson_id', 'user_id');
        }
}
```

And it's fields are:

```
lesson_id
title
course_id
```

As you see there is a OneToMany relation between `Course` and `Lesson` and a ManyToMany relation between `User` and `Course`.

`User` And `Course` Pivot table named ~course_user` have these fields :

```
course_id
user_id
```

In the other hand there is a ManyToMany relation between `User` and `Lesson`. pivot table for those named `lesson_user` and have these fields :

```
lesson_id
user_id
passed
```

`passed` field show status of a user in a lesson. if it was 0 ,means user has not passed it yet otherwise he passed it.

`User` Model is like :

```
class User extends Model
{
public function lessons()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lesson', 'lesson_user', 'user_id', 'lesson_id')
        }
public function courses ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'course_user', 'user_id', 'course_id');
    }
}
```

Now I want to get user courses and calculate percent of passed lessons in each Course via best way, for example nested where clauses.

Comment: Please share your migration and dummy data for us easier to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With inspiration from @KmasterYC answer I wrote bellow codes and all things work:

```
$userCourses =
            $currentUser->courses()
                ->take(3)
                ->get();


        $userCourses->map(function ($course) use ($currentUser) {

            $allLessonsCount = $course->lessons->count();

            $courseLessonID = $course->lessons->lists('lesson_id')->toArray();

            $userLessonsCount = $currentUser->lessons()
                ->where('passed', '=', true)
                ->whereIn('lesson_user.lesson_id', $courseLessonID)
                ->count();
            $percent          = round($userLessonsCount * 100 / $allLessonsCount);

            $course['percent'] = $percent;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be not the best way. But it is easy to understand and maintainable

```
$courses = $user->courses->map(function($cource){
            $all_lessions = $cource->pivot->count();
            $done_lessions = $cource->pivot->where(passed,'<>',0)->count();
            $percent = $done_lessions * 100 / $all_lessions;
            return $cource->push(['percent'=>$percent]);
        });
```

Now you can access through

```
foreach ($courses as $cource){
    $cource->percent;
    $cource->title; 
    //...
}
```

Comment: ,I try your solution But that has not exactly what I want.But it was useful for me and Gave me ideas to solve that. you can see at my answer to compare my solution and yourself.